# Android: how to skip chooser dialog during sharing

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to send one image file from my custom keyboard. I want to skip chooser dialoge and send the photo during sharing from my custom keyboard.

Below is my code

String root_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

```
            File imgFile = new  File(root_sd + "/My Photo/"+"Image-6260.jpg");

            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

            sharingIntent.setType("image/png");

            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(imgFile));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
            startActivity(sharingIntent);
```

[image]

Comment: how can you select  & send  without choosing ....

Comment: to where you share image with?

Comment: I have created custom keyboard to share photo and it work perfectly but when i select image to share to another application like whatsapp,facebook then one chooser dialog open (like Share via) this image so i just want to remove this chooser dialog and i want to share my image without chooser.

Comment: Actually from my custom keyboard i want to share some picture to another app like whatsapp,facebook. I want to use my custom keyboard in whatsapp and from my custom keyboad i want to share picture and it is working but i have to select whatsapp everytime so this reason i want to remove such chooser dialog and i can share my pic from my custom keybort to whatsapp directly.

Comment: To bypass the chooser you'll just need to set the package name of the target app in the intent.. but if you're targeting several apps I suppose you'll have to let the user choose which app.

Answer (score 1):

> you can share Image/Text via using package manager kindly check watsapp is installed before sending which i have not done in below example..

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        try {
            Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            waIntent.setType("text/plain");
            String text = "YOUR TEXT HERE";
            File imgFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/DCIM/CandyCam/" + "ktk.jpg");
            PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageInfo("com.whatsapp",
                    PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
            // Check if package exists or not. If not then code
            // in catch block will be called
            waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
            if (imgFile.exists()) {
                // waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
                waIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
                waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(imgFile));
            }
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent, "Share with"));

        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "WhatsApp not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
```